# What's wrong with this formula? ( while i'm making KPI)

Tags: powerbi

```
thisyearsales = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Sales Transactions',
        'Sales Transactions'[year]=2022
    ), 
    'Sales Transactions'[value]
)
```

```
lastyearsales = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Sales Transactions',
        'Sales Transactions'[year]=2021
    ), 
    'Sales Transactions'[value]
)
```

I don't understand why 'thisyearsales' cause error while 'lastyearsales' work right.
Related tables are below :

| Value | Date | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2021-01-01 | 2021 |
| 20000 | 2021-01-02 | 2021 |
| 10000 | 2021-01-03 | 2022 |

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in your DAX code.

Comment: Thanks, I should find out the other error

Comment: Please share the error It gives. It might lead us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error. Both measures are working fine for me.
However, I don't see why you are using an iterator function SUMX() when there is nothing to iterate over, while you actually need a function that changes the filter context, like CALCULATE() does:

```
Last Year Sales = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sales Transactions'[Value]),
    'Sales Transactions'[Year] = 2021
)
```

```
This Year Sales = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sales Transactions'[Value]),
    'Sales Transactions'[Year] = 2022
)
```